# Each data only appears 1 data, and when access each data the result is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, gtag.js

I have a product div which contains the `data-product` attribute, its value is object. And I want to put the product data into gtag.

but why when I do each, there is only 1 data? and when I want to access `data.id` and `data.name` why is it undefined?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const promotions = []
  
    $(".product-item").each(function(){
    const data = $(this).data('product');
    
    promotions.push({
      "id": data.id,
      "name": data.name
    })
  })
  
  //gtag('event', 'view_promotion', {
    //promotions
  //});
  
  $('.product-item').each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(e){
      const data = $(this).data('product')
      console.log(data)
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id" : 123, "name" : "Product 1"}'>
  Product 1
</div>
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id" : 124, "name" : "Product 2"}'>
  Product 2
</div>
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id" : 125, "name" : "Product 3"}'>
  Product 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [API](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) the attribute value must be a valid JSON including quoted property names.

In your case it is not properly formatted as JSON hence, it is not working. Format your `data-product` as valid JSON.

Once the JSON is fixed, to loop over promotions

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let promotions = []
  $(".product-item").each(function(){
    const data = $(this).data('product');
        
    promotions.push({
      "id": data.id,
      "name": data.name
    })
  })
      
           
  gtag('event', 'view_promotion', {
    promotions
  });
})
```

Comment: ahh i see, and how to foreach inside promotions array? cause in my snippet above it's only appear 1 data

Comment: @fikfe updated answer

Comment: i've edit my post above, when i click Product 3, why the data that appears is data Product 1? @vaibhavmande

Comment: @fikfe That is because you are accessing the first element each time. `const data = $('.product-item').data('product')` change this to `const data = $(this).data('product')`

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code, works for me:

```
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id":124,"name":"Product 1"}'>
    Product 1
</div>
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id":125,"name":"Product 2"}'>
    Product 2
</div>
<div class="product-item" data-product='{"id":126,"name":"Product 3"}'>
    Product 3
</div>
```

Comment: ahh i see, and how to foreach inside promotions array? cause in my snippet above it's only appear 1 data

Comment: @fikfe, you should retrieve 3 data byright. If you cannot debug it, you can try to create an object outside loop, push the looped value to object.promotions, then do one gtag call to send all data.

Comment: can you give me an example how to implement it?